# What is the difference between rendered entity and content in views 3?

Tags: 7, views

In the **Format** option for a view, the options include **Content** and **Rendered Entity**.

They both offer you a selection of view mode for the content. The former includes some extra options on comments/links.

So what is the point of **Rendered Entity** if it's a single configuration of **Content**?

Suspect I'm missing something!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At a guess...

The "Rendered Entity" format is available so *any* type of entity can be rendered. The "Content" format is only available for nodes, and as such can't be used generically.

Nodes are entities (as are users, taxonomy terms, and a whole host of others provided by contrib modules) and so just happen to be one of the 'items' that the "Rendered Entity" format can handle.

It also happens that Views already implements a format specifically for nodes ("Content"), so it does kind of look like there's repetition; but in reality it's not repetition at all, they're two separate things that just happen to have a bit of crossover in functionality.

Comment: Note that the "Rendered Entity" format is available only when you have the Entity API module installed. I found out the hard way about this ;-) So if both the "Content" and the "Rendered Entity" formats do work for you do pick the "Content" format as it comes built in with views. Cheers.